# Gatling check for java.io.IOException: Remotely closed

Tags: scala, gatling

While doing a test in gatling I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Remotely closed
```

which is expected (server cuts connection). How do I mark the test success or check for that exception?

Answer (score 2):

This exception means that the server closed the connection when the client (Gatling) was trying to write on it.

This might be in indication that you have to tune your keep-alive timeout to NOT match typical user think time, but such event will always happen.

But then, web browsers retry sending the request in case of such a failure.

Gatling can do that too, but it's disabled for now (will be enabled by default in 2.1.6). Until then, you can change the `maxRetry` value in gatling.conf.