# Kerberosmixed authentication ADFS mulesoft webservice consumer

Tags: java, mule, kerberos, adfs, webservices-client

I am trying to call ADFS from the Webservice Consumer component in MuleESB with the `kerberosmixed` authentication, but I cannot make it work. Does anyone know how to make it work?  My setup is as follows:

[My Transformer message building the message to send to adfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ahnQ.png)

[My Webserver Consumer General setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dY5g.png)

In my Security setup I have chosen `WS-Security Signature` and created a TLS Context as follows:

```
> <tls:context name="TLS_Context" doc:name="TLS Context">
>     <tls:trust-store path="mykeystore.jks" password="pass" type="jks"/>
>     <tls:key-store type="jks" path="mykeystore.jks" alias="myalias" password="pass" keyPassword="pass"/>
> </tls:context>
```

In the References tab i created a HTTP configuration with the following setup:

```
<http:request-config responseTimeout="30000" name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" host="myserver.local" protocol="HTTPS" basePath="https://myserver.local/adfs/services/trust/13/kerberosmixed" port="443" connectionIdleTimeout="60000">
        <http:basic-authentication username="user" password="pass" preemptive="true"/>
        <tls:context>
            <tls:trust-store path="mykeystore.jks" password="pass" type="jks"/>
            <tls:key-store type="jks" path="mykeystore.jks" alias="myalias" keyPassword="pass" password="pass"/>
        </tls:context>       
    </http:request-config>
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> ERROR 2016-06-14 09:50:01,640
>   [[fetchststoken].fetchststokenFlow.stage1.02]
>   org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
>   ******************************************************************************** Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is
>   of type: byte[] Type                  :
>   org.mule.api.MessagingException Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
>   Payload               : [B@3ab7cd6c JavaDoc               :
>   http ://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html 
>   ******************************************************************************** Exception stack is:
>   1. Remotely closed (java.io.IOException)
>   2. java.io.IOException: Remotely closed (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:349 (null)
>   3. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Remotely closed (java.io.IOException)
>   org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient:223
>   (null)
>   4. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>   org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287
>   (http ://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
>   ******************************************************************************** Root Exception stack trace: java.io.IOException: Remotely closed
>
> ---

The stack trace before the error is as follows:

```
 WARN  2016-06-14 09:50:01,636 [[fetchststoken].fetchststokenFlow.stage1.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:197) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:281) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:128) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:183) ~[mule-module-ws-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process(WSConsumer.java:107) ~[mule-module-ws-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:200) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:287) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:186) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumerConfig$1.process(WSConsumerConfig.java:127) ~[mule-module-ws-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:177) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.processNext(MuleUniversalConduit.java:387) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:282) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:193) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Remotely closed
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.send(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:223) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:282) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:186) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumerConfig$1.process(WSConsumerConfig.java:127) ~[mule-module-ws-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:177) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.processNext(MuleUniversalConduit.java:387) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:282) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:193) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:281) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:128) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:183) ~[mule-module-ws-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process(WSConsumer.java:107) ~[mule-module-ws-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Not appear to be an Authorization Issue. Try increasing response timeout Or enable Keep alive in socket  Reason:Refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078781/gatling-check-for-java-io-ioexception-remotely-closed

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it did not work.